# Finding bottleneck of nodejs webserver

Tags: node.js, mapbox, vector-tiles

I am using tileserver-gl-light to serve vector tiles. Currently I'm load testing the server, at specific values there is a drastic increase in request latency. However the CPU performance of the Virtual Machine - which I am using as server - stays below 20%. Does this mean I could decrease the latency by allocating more memory to the tileserver-gl-light proces, or does that have nothing to do with it?

Comment: are You doing load test from same machine? I mean it may occur the bandwidth deficiency of requester part.

Comment: @num8er No I'm doing load tests from different machines. Would it be smart to do it from the same machine?

Comment: I mean Your requests are going from same client machine? Let's say 1 server <=> 1 client (does N requests)   - in this case Your client device consumes network traffic and in case of "ddos" it uses all bandwidth, so You'll get latency. For that case it's not serverside issue, it's normal problem of clientside. Let's say Your server's bw is 1Gbit, but client's bw is 20Mbit, so if client will decide to open 20 browser tabs and watch something from Your server, then client will have latency of network bw. That's not Your server's problem.

Comment: @num8er Thanks, that's probably the issue!